# How to make an addon with C#?

Tags: scripting, add-on

In order to get more performance and knowing that C# is cross-platform. I would like to start working in that language by creating a simple addon for Blender with it.

The addon would not need to be entirely in C#, it may be only a part.

A simple example would also be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as much as I hate python myself , the performance you will supposedly gain with C# will be lost when you have to use a wrapper for blender's pythonic-API.

Comment: @R00t Not necessarily, if the heaviest functions are done in C#

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's contrary to the sense of the community as defined in the answer to [this question](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6), which specifically defines questions about development in C/C++ as out of scope.

Comment: Have a look at [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/) - I can't say whether it will work easily with blender. If you are after more performance have a look at [cython](http://cython.org/) it turns python into c-code that compiles into a binary python module. The [cubesurfer addon](http://pyroevil.com/cubesurfer-addon-download/) is an example of using cython.